# Passing structure through Udp socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to pass a structure through a udp socket. The structure consists of two arrays. Each array is filled with a value by a thread and then the structure is passed to the server. The server will then print the content of one of the arrays. The issue is when the server prints the array, it prints all zeros. There should be values in the array and this is not correct. Am I passing the structure incorrectly?

Below is my code

Server

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define PORT 8080 



struct values {
       int serviceArray[100]; 
       int portArray[100];
       }input;


int main()
{


 int sockfd; 


    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr; 



    // Creating socket file descriptor 

    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) { 

        perror("socket creation failed"); 

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

    } 



    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr)); 



    // Filling server information 

    servaddr.sin_family    = AF_INET; // IPv4 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 



    // Bind the socket with the server address 

    if ( bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) 

    { 

        perror("bind failed"); 

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

    } 
    else
    {
        printf("Bind successfull\n");
    }




    int len;
    sleep(2);
   recvfrom(sockfd, &input, sizeof(input), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &len); 




    // After chatting close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
   int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", input.serviceArray[j]);

        }



}
```

Client

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PORT 8080

int SIZE = 100;
int counter = 0;
int semaphore = 1; //set to false

struct values 
       {
       int serviceArray[100]; 
       int portArray[100];
       }input;

void callServer()
{
    int sockfd; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) { 
        perror("socket creation failed");    
    } 

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr)); 


    // Filling server information 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");



    int n;
    int len = sizeof(servaddr); 
    int i;
    for(i =0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%d\n", input.serviceArray[i]);


    if(sendto(sockfd, &input, sizeof(input), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, len) < 0)
      {
      perror("sendto()");
      }


    // close the socket 
    close(sockfd); 
} 



int arraySearch(int number){
    int i=0; 
    for(i=0; i< 100; i++){
        if(input.serviceArray[i] == number)
        {
            return 0; //is found
        }

    }

    return 1;
}


void *createService()
{

    while(counter < SIZE)
    {
        sleep(1);
        if(semaphore ==1)
        {

            int randomValue = rand() % SIZE;

            if(arraySearch(randomValue) == 1)
            {
                input.serviceArray[counter] = randomValue;
                input.portArray[counter] = randomValue + PORT;
                printf("Thread 1 is adding service number: %d and port number: %d\n", input.serviceArray[counter], input.portArray[counter]);
                semaphore = 0;//unlock
                counter = counter + 1;
                callServer();

            }
        }
    }
}
void *removeService()
{

    while(counter < SIZE)
    {
        sleep(3);
        if(semaphore ==0)
        {
            printf("Thread 2 is removing service number: %d and port number: %d\n", input.serviceArray[counter - 1], input.portArray[counter - 1]);
            input.serviceArray[counter -1] = 0;
            input.portArray[counter - 1] = 0;
            semaphore = 1; //lock
            callServer();

        }
    }
}



int main(void)
{

    //create threads
        pthread_t thread_id1, thread_id2;  


        pthread_create(&thread_id1, NULL, createService, NULL);
        //pthread_create(&thread_id2, NULL, removeService, NULL); 


        pthread_join(thread_id1, NULL);  
        pthread_join(thread_id2, NULL); 



}
```

Comment: With `sendto` and `recvfrom` you should check that the return value is equal to the number of bytes you expected to send or receive.

Comment: @Bodo Unlike TCP which is stream-based, UDP is message-based.  `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` in UDP can send/receive only complete messages, not partial messages. So, yes, always check return values, but just know that the particular byte count is not as important for UDP. If you ask them to send/read X bytes, the return value will always be either -1 on error or X bytes on success (unless you perform a peek operation on `recvfrom()`, that is).

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right, `sendto` should either send the complete datagram or return an error, but `recvfrom` returns the length of the received datagram which may be less than what the receiver wantet to get or it may indicate that the message was truncated. Both probably indicate a bug.

Comment: Sorry, `bind(2)` system call binds your local address part, nothing is done for the remote part.  use `connect(2)` for that, or put the server address in the address part of the `sendto(2)` system call.  There's no need to `bind(2)` to send the packet.. this will make the kernel to use an ephemeral port and to select the right address for the packet.